# Returning a value after writing to a file is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Hi I am writing a function in Node JS for which I have to return a filepath. My problem is in that function I am writing to a file and I want after writing to a file is finished then my return should work. Before looking into code, I know this can be duplicate and I have really did a research on this but I am not just being able to get there. I have tried using callback but the problem is I want to return a value which is already defined. So, before making any judgement calls for duplicate or lack of research, please read the code.

Also, tried to return value in fs.append callback but still did not solved.

My function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports.createDownloadFile = (request) => {
  let filePath;
  if (request) {
    const userID = xyz;
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, userID.concat('.txt'));
    fs.open(filePath, 'w', (err) => {
      if (err) throw new Error('FILE_NOT_PRESENT');
      fs.appendFile(filePath, 'content to write');
    });
  }

  return filePath;
};
```

I am getting the filePath where I am calling function, it's just at that time file is empty that is why I want to return after file is written completely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use promises like this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports.createDownloadFile = (request) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let filePath;
        if (request) {
            const userID = xyz;
            filePath = path.join(__dirname, userID.concat('.txt'));
            fs.open(filePath, 'w', (err) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else
                    fs.appendFile(filePath, 'content to write', (err) => {
                        if (err) 
                            reject(err)
                        else
                        resolve(filePath)
                    });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

and call it like this :

```
createDownloadFile(requeset).then(filePath => {
    console.log(filePath)
})
```

or use sync functions without Promises:

```
module.exports.createDownloadFile = (request) => {
        let filePath;
        if (request) {
            const userID = xyz;
            filePath = path.join(__dirname, userID.concat('.txt'));
            fs.openSync(filePath,"w");
            fs.appendFileSync(filePath, 'content to write');
        }
        return filePath;
};
```

Comment: That's correct I just forgot to mention, I have tried with Promises. Is there any other way without using promises?

Answer (score 0):

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) allow you to structure code and return values more like traditional synchronous code. [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#util_util_promisify_original) can help promisify regular node callback functions.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const fsAppendFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.appendFile)
const fsOpenAsync = util.promisify(fs.open)

module.exports.createDownloadFile = async (request) => {
  if (!request) throw new Error('nope')
  const userID = xyz
  let filePath = path.join(__dirname, userID.concat('.txt'))
  let fd = await fsOpenAsync(filePath, 'w')
  await fsAppendFileAsync(fd, 'content to write')
  return filePath
};
```

Note that [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) are ES2017 and require [Node.js 7.6+](https://v8project.blogspot.fr/2016/10/v8-release-55.html) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Opening a file with `w` creates or truncates the file and promises will reject on errors that are thrown so I've left the error handler out. You can use `try {} catch (e) {}` blocks to handle specific errors.

The [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) promise library is helpful too, especially [`Promise.promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) which creates the promisified `Async` methods for you:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
fs.appendFileAsync('file', 'content to write')
```